# Can't access data on a JSON fetch past graphql (React.js)

Tags: json, reactjs

I started a little test project (code is public): https://github.com/GhostCrawl3r/Instagram-Website-Addon

I managed to pull data from Instagram in a JSON fetch successfully:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import InstagramProfileBox from './InstagramProfileBox/IGProfilebox.component';
import {PostCard} from './IGPostCard/IGPostCard.component';

class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    
    this.state =
        {
            instagramUser: [],
            photos: []
        };
  }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://www.instagram.com/the_nickmorgan/?__a=1')
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                  instagramUser: data.graphql.user
              })
          })
    }
    
   
    
    render()
      {
          const instagramData = this.state.instagramUser;
          
          console.log(instagramData)
          
          console.log('This is your name ' + instagramData.full_name);
          
          return (
              <div className='App'>
                  <div className='ProfileHolder'>
                  <InstagramProfileBox instagramData={instagramData} />
                  <hr/>
                  <PostCard/>
                  
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
              
          )

      }
  }
    
    export default App;
```

Thats fanatic as it validates in the console log that I can pull the data.. this is a far cry from when I first made this post an hour ago before editing...
Now however I can't get the updated state from the fetch to display things like the updated full name, background image etc.
This is the component itself rendering all the lovely code:

```
import React from "react";
import './IGProfileBox.styles.scss';

const profilePicURL = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518806118471-f28b20a1d79d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80';

const InstagramProfileBox = (instagramData, ...otherProps) =>
    <div className='ProfileBoxHolder'>
    <div className='grid'>
    <div className='profileBox'>
        <img alt='ProfilePicture' src={profilePicURL} /></div>
    
        <div className='detailsContainerGrid'>
        <div className='displayName'>
        <h1>{ instagramData.length ? `${instagramData.full_name}`
                : 'loading......' }</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div className='statbox-grid'>
            <div className='statbox'><h1>5k</h1><p>Posts</p></div>
            <div className='statbox'><h1>50K</h1><p>Followers</p></div>
            <div className='statbox'><h1>500</h1><p>Following</p></div>
        </div>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div className='buttongrid'>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
        <button className='userbuttons'>SocialStuff</button>
    </div>
    </div>

export default InstagramProfileBox;
```

---

This is really driving me mad. I'm not sure if this is a graphql thing, as I've not yet to progress to learning that yet (Redux is my main concern right now).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data and the error message as text, not a link to a pic.

Comment: Hey @code-Apprentice I just made that edit now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that `instagramData.user` is `undefined`. Most likely this happens the first time the component is rendered before the request to instagram comes back with a response. You need to handle this situation gracefully by either not displaying the user data at all until the response comes back or displaying some kind of static place holder. One way to do this is with conditional rendering:

```
{ instagramData && <h1>instagramData.user.full_name</h1> || <h1>Loading...</h1> }
```

You also have a problem with the function declaration:

```
const InstagramProfileBox = (instagramData, ...otherProps) => { ... }
```

This declares a function that takes multiple parameters. However, React will only ever pass a single parameter that is an object with all the props. One fix is to use destructuring syntax to get the `instagramData from the props parameter:

```
const InstagramProfileBox = ({instagramData, ...otherProps}) ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just tried this out but I got the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'full_name' of undefined` - It can't read the .full_name from the Json.

Comment: I managed to tweak the code you gave me to :  instagramData ?`${instagramData.full_name}` : 'loading......' } -> Still returns undefined as the name, however I can get it to console.log the name in the app.js

Comment: I just want to point out that you are using a string template literal to render the user name. Instead you can just use the variable directly. Since it is inside `{}` in JSX it will be rendered if it has a value. This doesn't address the core problem, but is considered good practice.

Comment: @NickMorgan See my edit with the next fix. Note that for future references, when someone answers your question here, you should accept the answer that helps you by clicking the checkmark. If you have additional follow-up questions, you should make a new post instead of editing the existing question.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help and explanation. I'm very new to Stack overflow, so apologies for not doing this the right way round. 
Kind regards, N